# ASP.net Web API - Add Array Name to Output

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to change the json output from the Web API. Say I have a objects like People, the current output would be like:

```
[{name:"John", sex:"M"},{name:"Simon", sex:"M"}]
```

However I would like the output to be like:

```
{"people":[{name:"John", sex:"M"},{name:"Simon", sex:"M"}]}
```

Any Ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Option 1 - Create new model**

Instead of returning

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
```

return

```
public People Get()
```

where

```
public class People {
    public IEnumerable<Person> People {get; set;}
}
```

**Option 2 - return dynamic**

Instead of returning

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
```

return

```
public dynamic Get() {
    IEnumerable<Person> p = //initialize to something;
    return new {people = p};
}
```

**Option 3 - modify JsonMediaTypeFormatter**

You can still return

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
```

but add the following class:

```
public class PeopleAwareJsonMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        if ((typeof (IEnumerable<People>).IsAssignableFrom(type)))
        {
            value = new {people = value};
        }
        return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, writeStream, content, transportContext);
    }
}
```

now in WebApiConfig just register the new formatter instead of old JSON one:

```
config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new PeopleAwareMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume variable name of list object is `PersonList` which returns

```
[{name:"John", sex:"M"},{name:"Simon", sex:"M"}]
```

You can simply do returning as following without pain

```
       return new
        {
            people = PersonList
        };
```

then you'll have

```
{"people":[{name:"John", sex:"M"},{name:"Simon", sex:"M"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be having a `DTO` for this `JSON`. So , what you have to do is just have a container for your array.

```
public class ReturnedJson
{
   public IList<People> People {get;set;}
}

 public class People
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public string sex{get;set;}
}
```

This is my assumption that you have a DTO for this json, because you haven't shown any code.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Filip W's second option, this nicely pulls from database since List implements IEnumerable:

> public dynamic Get() {
>
> ```
> List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
>
> using (DataTable dt = db.ExecuteDataTable("PeopleSelect")) {
>     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
>         personList.Add(new Person { name = (string)dr["name"], ...});
>     }
> }
>
> return new { people = personList };
> ```
>
> }